# Do both CPUs on a dual socket system need their own set of RAM?

Tags: cpu, sockets

I have a server motherboard with two sockets that support triple-channel memory.  Each processor has 6 DIMMs.  If I plan to use both CPUs, should I populate at least three of the DIMMs on each processor?  Or can I only populate 3 of the DIMMs for the first CPU?  Would the 2nd CPU be used in this scenario?

Comment: I think it might help to say which sockel the mainboard has. I don't know much about it but I can imagine that a Sandybridge Xeon might need it's own ram because the RAM controller is in the CPU. All the RAM will be shown in the operating system anyway, but I don't know about the facts.

Comment: This is the Westmere socket, which also has an integrated memory controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends

### Symmetrical Multi-Processing

"In computing, symmetric multiprocessing (SMP) involves a multiprocessor computer hardware architecture where two or more identical processors are connected to a single shared main memory"

<sub>(from Wikipedia.)</sub>

### Non-Uniform Memory Access

However CPU chips have several levels of cache (which is also memory) and NUMA allows for processors to each have access to their own memory.

I believe AMD's HyperTransport and Intel's QuickPath Interconnect allow for NUMA on certain CPUs.

Comment: I do remember seeing an option for NUMA in the BIOS.  I will look into what this does.  Thanks.